# Unit testing controller with dbcontext parameter

Tags: .net, xunit

At the moment I'm (unsuccessfully) trying to unit test my ToDoItem controller.
This is the ToDoItem class:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

    public TodoItem()
    {

    }
}
```

This class is used in the DbContext class, like so

```
public class ToDoContext : DbContext
{
    public ToDoContext(DbContextOptions<ToDoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<TestApp.Data.TodoItem> TodoItem { get; set; }

}
```

Now this is the to be tested GET function of ToDoItemsController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ToDoContext _context;

    public TodoItemsController(ToDoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/TodoItems/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
    {
        var todoItem = await _context.TodoItem.FindAsync(id);

        if (todoItem == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return todoItem;
    }
```

Executing this XUnit test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetTodoItem_WithUnexistingItem_ReturnsNotFound()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dbContextStub = new Mock<ToDoContext>();
        dbContextStub.Setup(context => context.TodoItem.FindAsync(It.IsAny<long>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((TodoItem)null);

        var controller = new TodoItemsController(dbContextStub.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await controller.GetTodoItem(long.MinValue);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(result.Result);
    }
```

Provides this error:
[image]

My thoughts were that it has to do with the actual DB connection, but I'm not too sure.
Can anyone help me to get this UT to work?

Comment: A couple issues 1. Only virtual members can be mocked, so you'll need to add the virtual keyword on TodoItem property on your DbContext.  2) AFAIK, Moq does not support method chaining within Setup, you'll need to create a Mock<DbSet<TodoItem>> which is setup as the return value for the TodoItem property, then you'll need to setup the FindAsync method on this Mock<DbSet<TodoItem>> as well.   
Consider not writing unit tests for this and instead write integration tests leveraging an in-memory db provider.  Consider an abstraction that your controller uses instead of directly using dbcontext.